# Xinetd server connection refused

Tags: linux, fedora, telnet, xinetd

I'm using xinetd on Fedora. 
I put a file called telnet inside the etc/xinetd.d folder with the following content:

```
service telnet
{   
    disable = yes
    id = telnet
    socket_type = stream
    protocol = tcp
    wait = no
    user = root
    server = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
}
```

I know xinetd is running because when I do service xinetd status it says active (running). 
When I do netstat -nltp nothing seems to be running on port 23 and 'telnet localhost' returns connection refused. Any ideas?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add that and then fail to tell `xinetd` to re-read the configuration files? You can use `kill -HUP $(< /var/run/xinetd.pid)` to restart it with a re-read of configuration files in a typical install.

Comment: There seems to be some miscommunication. If you have already edited the config file, and `xinetd` is currently running, then you have to let `xinetd` know to read the new config file. That's what the `kill` does.

Comment: I understand, but I have never edited the config file, therefore that might be the problem. Maybe there's something I should edit to make it work.

Comment: Oh, maybe change `disable = yes` to `disable = no` and then restart.

Comment: Thanks, that was it